# Are there any Social Responsibility Index funds or ETFs?

Tags: investing, etf, index-fund

Are there any Index Funds or ETFs that focus on [Socially Responsible Investing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socially_responsible_investing), or will I have to choose my own basket of stocks?

Comment: Old question, but for anyone who arrives here looking for ETFs, ETFdb [has a list](http://etfdb.com/type/investment-style/socially-responsible/).

Comment: @Kimberly Could you make that an answer?  That's probably a better answer than the one I accepted a year ago.

Comment: I posted an answer to replace the comment about ETFs.  An ethical-investing tag was recently created.  Would you add it to this question?

Comment: The answer to the question as posed is "yes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vanguard offers an index fund. Their FTSE Social Index Fund. For more information on it, [go here](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0213&FundIntExt=INT).

Comment: And these companies are included in the top 10 holdings: Apple Inc., Bank of America Corp. and McDonald's Corp. Although they meet the fund's definition of responsible, they don't meet mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this site for the funds http://www.socialinvest.org/resources/mfpc/ I'm not aware of any etfs. I'm sure some exist though.

Answer (score 1):

TIAA-Cref has their Social Choice Equity Fund, which is a Large Blend primarily equity fund that invests given the following consideration:

> The Fund primarily invests in companies that are screened by MSCI Inc. (“MSCI”) to favor companies that meet or exceed certain environmental, social and governance (“ESG”) criteria. The Fund does this by investing in U.S. companies included in one or more MSCI ESG Indices that meet or exceed the screening criteria described below.
>
> Prior to being eligible for inclusion in the MSCI ESG Indices, companies are subject to an ESG performance evaluation conducted by MSCI, consisting of numerous factors. The ESG evaluation process favors companies that are: (i) strong stewards of the environment; (ii) devoted to serving local communities where they operate and to human rights and philanthropy; (iii) committed to higher labor standards for their own employees and those in the supply chain; (iv) dedicated to producing high-quality and safe products; and (v) managed in an exemplary and ethical manner.

https://www.tiaa.org/public/offer/products/mutual-funds/responsible-investing

Answer (score 1):

Index funds: Some of the funds [listed by US SIF](http://ussif.org/resources/mfpc/) are index funds.

ETFs: [ETFdb has a list](http://etfdb.com/type/investment-style/socially-responsible/), though it's pretty short at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

At the other end of the spectrum is the [VICEX fund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice_Fund).  it invests in industries such as tobacco, gaming, defense/weapons, liquor and other companies whose products or services are widely considered not to be socially responsible

Comment: Not related at all, but very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [iShares Jantzi Social Index Fund](http://ca.ishares.com/product_info/fund/overview/XEN.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Calvert Funds. They have a variety of "socially responsible" funds with published selection standards.

Beware of mixing personal politics with business.

Comment: If you are not willing to put your money where you mouth is what is the point?

Comment: Chad - the point was to answer the question, which he did. Do you feel that every factual answer should only be from one who actually invests in the company/fund in their answer? I don't suggest buying gold, but I know how to discuss Gold ETF, and the tax implications.